# Is the following implementation of RandomizedSearchCV right?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was studying Machine Learning through the book ["Hands-on Machine Learning"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/) and there was an exercise to implement [`SelectFromModel`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html). The solution to the exercise given by the book runs the following code:

```
param_distribs = {
        'svr__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf'],
        'svr__C': loguniform(20, 200_000),
        'svr__gamma': expon(scale=1.0),
    }

svr_pipeline = Pipeline([("preprocessing", preprocessing), ("svr", SVR())])
rnd_search = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_pipeline,
                                param_distributions=param_distribs,
                                n_iter=50, cv=3,
                                scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                                verbose=2,
                                random_state=42)

rnd_search.fit(housing.iloc[:5000], housing_labels.iloc[:5000])

selector_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessing', preprocessing),
    ('selector', SelectFromModel(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42),
                                 threshold=0.005)),  # min feature importance
    ('svr', SVR(C=rnd_search.best_params_["svr__C"],
                gamma=rnd_search.best_params_["svr__gamma"],
                kernel=rnd_search.best_params_["svr__kernel"])),
])

selector_rmses = -cross_val_score(selector_pipeline,
                                  housing.iloc[:5000],
                                  housing_labels.iloc[:5000],
                                  scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error",
                                  cv=3)
pd.Series(selector_rmses).describe()

count        3.000000
mean     56211.362086
std       1922.002802
min      54150.008629
25%      55339.929909
50%      56529.851189
75%      57242.038815
max      57954.226441
dtype: float64
```

Ok. This result was worse than the previous exercise, and the author suggests: "Oh well, feature selection does not seem to help. But maybe that's just because the threshold we used was not optimal. Perhaps try tuning it using random search or grid search?"

Well, for the porpuse of learning, I tried to implement the suggestion. The following is my attempt:

```
param_distribs = {
    'selector__threshold': uniform(0, 0.05),
    'svr__C': loguniform(20, 200_000),
    'svr__gamma': expon(scale=1.0),
    'svr__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf']
}

selector_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessing', preprocessing),
    ('selector', SelectFromModel(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42))),
    ('svr', SVR()),
])

rnd_search = RandomizedSearchCV(selector_pipeline,
                                param_distributions=param_distribs,
                                n_iter=50, cv=3,
                                scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                                verbose=2,
                                random_state=42)

rnd_search.fit(housing.iloc[:5000], housing_labels.iloc[:5000])

# Get the best parameters
best_threshold = rnd_search.best_params_['selector__threshold']
best_svr_C = rnd_search.best_params_['svr__C']
best_svr_gamma = rnd_search.best_params_['svr__gamma']
best_svr_kernel = rnd_search.best_params_['svr__kernel']

# Update the pipeline with the best parameters
selector_pipeline.set_params(
    selector__threshold=best_threshold,
    svr__C=best_svr_C,
    svr__gamma=best_svr_gamma,
    svr__kernel=best_svr_kernel
)
```

But then the last output seems worse than the previous one:

```
selector_rmses = -cross_val_score(selector_pipeline,
                                  housing.iloc[:5000],
                                  housing_labels.iloc[:5000],
                                  scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error",
                                  cv=3)
pd.Series(selector_rmses).describe()

count        3.000000
mean     56713.692587
std       2011.579891
min      55241.366017
25%      55567.689915
50%      55894.013813
75%      57449.855872
max      59005.697931
dtype: float64
```

I just want to interpret the result: maybe the `RandomizedSearchCV` for the `threshold` want't the solution, maybe optimizing the threshold wouldn't help anyway. But a more fundamental question for me is: is my implementation right? I am not 100% secure that this is the right way to do this. Like I said, I am studying and learning then I am not sure about the code. If this is right, what can be a next step to try a better performance?